# Loan amortization schedule

Tags: excel, vba

I need to generate a loan table for an interest rate 8%, loan life 15 years, and initial loan amount £200,000. I've used the below VBA code on excel 2010, but it is not displaying the table correctly, this is the code that I've used;

```
Sub LoanSchedule()

Dim intRate, loanLife, initLoan, payment

intRate = InputBox("Input Interest rate:")
loanLife = InputBox("Input Loan life:")
initLoan = InputBox("Input Loan amount:")

Cells(4, 2).Value = intRate
Cells(5, 2).Value = loanLife
Cells(6, 2).Value = initLoan

payment = Pmt(intRate, loanLife, -initLoan)

'Year-beg Bal    Annual Payment  Interest Component  Prinicipal Repaid   Year-end Bal
 Dim yearBegBal, intComp, prinComp, yearEndBal

outRow = 10
yearBegBal = LoanAmtBal

For rowNum = 1 To loanLife
intComp = yearBegBal * intRate
prinComp = payment - intComp
yearEndBal = yearBegBal - prinComp

Cells(outRow + rowNum, 1).Value = rowNum
Cells(outRow + rowNum, 2).Value = yearBegBal
Cells(outRow + rowNum, 3).Value = payment
Cells(outRow + rowNum, 4).Value = intComp
Cells(outRow + rowNum, 5).Value = prinComp
Cells(outRow + rowNum, 6).Value = yearEndBal

yearBegBal = yearEndBal
Next rowNum

End Sub
```

as I am a beginner to VBA, would someone be able to help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `LoanAmtBal` is not defined and used directly, which I believe is causing the issues...

```
yearBegBal = LoanAmtBal
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of what the OP was trying to do...I needed it myself.

```
Sub LoanSchedule()

Dim intRate, loanLife, initLoan, payment As Double
Dim yearBegBal, intComp, prinComp, yearEndBal, intTot, prinTot, fvloan As Currency

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Delete

intRateYrs = InputBox("Input Interest rate (Annual):")
loanLifeYrs = InputBox("Input Loan life (Years):")
initLoan = InputBox("Input Loan amount:")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

intRateMths = (intRateYrs / 100) / 12
loanLifeMths = loanLifeYrs * 12

Cells(4, 2).Value = Format(intRateYrs, "#.##") & " %"
Cells(4, 3).Value = Format(intRateMths, "Percent")
Cells(5, 2).Value = loanLifeYrs
Cells(5, 3).Value = loanLifeMths
Cells(6, 2).Value = Format(initLoan, "Currency")

payment = Pmt(intRateMths, loanLifeMths, -initLoan)
Cells(7, 2).Value = Format(payment, "Currency")

outRow = 10
intTot = 0
prinTot = 0
fvloan = 0

Cells(10, 2).Value = "Beginning Balance"
Cells(10, 3).Value = "Payment"
Cells(10, 4).Value = "Interest"
Cells(10, 5).Value = "Principal"
Cells(10, 6).Value = "End Balance"
Cells(10, 7).Value = "Total Interest"
Cells(10, 8).Value = "Total Principal"
Cells(10, 9).Value = "Total Repaid"
yearBegBal = initLoan

For rowNum = 1 To loanLifeMths
    intComp = yearBegBal * intRateMths
    prinComp = payment - intComp
    yearEndBal = yearBegBal - prinComp

    intTot = intTot + intComp
    prinTot = prinTot + prinComp
    fvloan = intTot + prinTot

    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 1).Value = rowNum
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 2).Value = Format(yearBegBal, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 3).Value = Format(payment, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 4).Value = Format(intComp, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 5).Value = Format(prinComp, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 6).Value = Format(yearEndBal, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 7).Value = Format(intTot, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 8).Value = Format(prinTot, "Currency")
    Cells(outRow + rowNum, 9).Value = Format(fvloan, "Currency")

    yearBegBal = yearEndBal
Next rowNum

ActiveSheet.Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Rows("11:11").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Range("A1").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Briefly explaining what you've done to address the OP's code would be helpful; e.g. what concept(s) did they miss?